# What is the difference between file and allFile in the GraphQL query in Gatsby?

Tags: graphql, gatsby

In my GraphiQL explorer, it appears that I can query `file` or `allFile`, but I don't really understand what the difference between the two is. In fact, every query appears to be "duplicated" in this manner. Can someone explain, or point me to some documentation that explains the difference and when I should use one over the other? [image: GraphQL query]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`allFile` (notice the `all` prefix) stands for all GraphQL assets of `file` node type that Gatsby has inferred using the [`gatsby-source-filesystem`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-source-filesystem/), while `file` is an isolated node that would need to be filtered to get the specific object.

In other words, `allFile` is exposing all files in your project (at least the ones that Gatsby is aware of), which will give you an array of `nodes` while `file` is only pointing to a specific GraphQL node. This single and isolated node normally needs to be filtered to get them among the rest.
The same reasoning applies to `allMdx` and `mdx`, `allSite` and `site`, etc.

For example, using `allMdx` example (node created by [`gatsby-plugin-mdx`](https://www.gatsbyjs.com/plugins/gatsby-plugin-mdx)): let's say you have a blog project where you store your posts in MDX files. In your `gatsby-node.js` you will query for `allMdx` node in order to get all posts, then, you will loop through the results and create dynamic pages for each post (using `createPage` method). In the post template (the template that each specific post will use), instead of querying for `allMdx`, you will need to use `mdx` because it's pointing specifically to a single `mdx` node.
Of course, in your template, you can still use `allMdx`, for it's not the optimal GraphQL node since you have a specific `mdx` that will be your single post, filtered by some unique value like the `slug`, the `id`, etc.